# To upload file using SFTP in C#

Tags: c#

I have created code for uploading file to SFTP remote server, But it shows error as:

> The given path's format is not supported.

I have given my code and sample details. I am sure the path which i am providing is incorrect.

my dll for SFTP is:

```
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Sftp;
```

sample data:

```
server: 192.168.1.1
remotemachine(fileZilla LocalPath):"C:\Program Files\JSCAPE MFT Server\users\hind\scope"
```

Code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    source = @"E:\To_Upload\tests_example.xls";//

    destination = "sftp://scope@hind/" + @" C:\Program Files\JSCAPE MFT Server\users\hind\scope";
    host = "hind";
    username = "scope";
    password = "S@ssw0rd987";
    port = 22;  
    UploadSFTPFile(host, username, password, source, destination, port);
}


public static void UploadSFTPFile(string host, string username, string password, string sourcefile, string destinationpath, int port)
{
   try
   {
     using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
     {
          client.Connect();
          client.ChangeDirectory(destinationpath);
          using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourcefile, FileMode.Open))
          {
               client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
               client.UploadFile(fs, Path.GetFileName(sourcefile));
          }
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, "UploadSFTPFile");
   }
}
```

Kindly rectify my problem. and how to pass SFTP path in destination

thanks

Comment: Your destination path is invalid, it should be only path, something like this for Windows machine: `destination = @"C:\Program Files\JSCAPE MFT Server\users\hind\scope";` and something like `/home/hind/scope` for Linux based systems.

Comment: Even i have tried this, This throws an error as "could not find part of the path" "C:\Program Files\JSCAPE MFT Server\users\hind\scope".

Kindly note iam uploading from my local system to server machine, Then how should we provide path for SFTP

Comment: Does that directory exist? Is it accesible? E.g. you migh try even on Windows changing remote path to `hind/scope`. What if you don't change remote path at all? Where does the file get copied (if somewhere at all)?

Comment: I have opened FileZilla and tried to copy a file manually from local to server, its copying perfectly, After copying local to server in FileZilla, by right clicking copied file in filezilla it shows url   as "sftp://scope@hind/Hana"

Comment: What if you don't call `ChangeDirectory` at all? Where is the file copied then? Is copying successful?

Comment: What is the WorkingDirectory prior to trying ChangeDirectory - you may be able to just change directory relative to the default rather than the root. With FileZilla can you access your full path?

Comment: i have found the solution, and it has copied successfully, Destination path which i have mentioned as "/Foldername";

Comment: thanks for your feedback